# File Upload to Amazon S3 via Groovy

Tags: amazon-web-services, groovy, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload a file to Amazon S3 bucket using Groovy script. I tried the following code

```
@Grab( 'net.java.dev.jets3t:jets3t:0.9.0' )
import org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestS3Service
import org.jets3t.service.security.AWSCredentials
import org.jets3t.service.model.*
import java.io.*;

bucketName='bucketname'
accessKey='accesskey'
secretKey='secretkey'
folder='D:/'

public putS3() {}
def login = new AWSCredentials( accessKey, secretKey )
def expiry = new GregorianCalendar( 2011,0,1 ).time
def s3 = new RestS3Service( login ) 
def bucket = new S3Bucket( bucketName )
args.each{fileName->
        def key="$folder/$fileName"
        def s3obj=new S3Object(bucket,newFile('D:/sample.txt'))
        s3obj.key = key
        println "\nUploading $fileName to $bucketName/$key"
        s3obj = s3.putObject( bucket, s3obj )
        def link = s3.createSignedGetUrl( bucketName, key, login, expiry, false )
        println "$fileName : $link"
        }
```

code in the args block is not getting executed. When I execute this in Groovy Console it displays the result as []. Kindly help me where am I going wrong?

Comment: When you run it in the groovy console, you're not passing any args

Comment: @tim_yates: How should I pass args. Kindly suggest me.

Comment: `groovy <scriptname> <filename arg>...`

Comment: @JamesA: Is it not possible to pass the args in the code it self? When I execute the code, the file should be posted to amazon S3 server. Is that possible?

Comment: Just set an args variable containing filenames? Not sure I understand

Comment: Also, don't think you need `import java.io.*;`, not sure what `public putS3() {}` is supposed to do and I suspect `newFile('D:/sample.txt')` is wrong

Comment: @tim_yates: Can you please modify my code. I have a project requirement of sending files to Amazon S3 server. When I execute the code file should automatically posted to amazon S3 bucket. I want to define the file implicity in the code itself. How to do that? Could you please provide me the details?

Comment: @tim_yates: Here is the code which I have taken http://blog.thomnichols.org/2009/10/upload-to-s3-with-groovy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have an S3 account to test with but here's a simplied example based upon the [documenation](https://jets3t.s3.amazonaws.com/toolkit/code-samples.html):

```
import org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestS3Service
import org.jets3t.service.model.S3Bucket
import org.jets3t.service.model.S3Object
import org.jets3t.service.security.AWSCredentials

@Grab('net.java.dev.jets3t:jets3t:0.9.0')

accessKey = 'accesskey'
secretKey = 'secretkey'
bucketName = 'bucketname'
fileName = 'D:\\sample.txt'

credentials = new AWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey)
service = new RestS3Service(credentials)
bucket = new S3Bucket(bucketName)
file = new File(fileName)
fileObject = new S3Object(file)
fileObject.key = fileName
service.putObject(bucket, fileObject)
expiryTime = new Date() + 1 // 24 hours from current date
link = service.createSignedGetUrl(bucket.name, fileObject.key, expiryTime)
println "$fileName : $link"
```

Answer (score 1):

I came accross that example recently as I attempt to code a quick groovy to upload to a S3 Bucket, however, all my attempts have ended up with 301

```
org.jets3t.service.S3ServiceException: Service Error Message. -- ResponseCode: 301, ResponseStatus: Moved Permanently, XML Error Message: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Error><Code>PermanentRedirect</Code><Message>The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.</Message><Endpoint>bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com</Endpoint><Bucket>bucketname</Bucket><RequestId>4CF5EDE9EF604DBB</RequestId><HostId>89KoQLvd93pXhnxJGcEaziSrSOPFRNXqbfPfY7LTe03z5rvVLAVx7UnFkts/Qe1fQ7eOWsaAL7A=</HostId></Error>
    at org.jets3t.service.S3Service.putObject(S3Service.java:2358)
    at org.jets3t.service.S3Service$putObject.call(Unknown Source)
    at awsBucketDrop.run(awsBucketDrop.groovy:21)
```

At first I though this was a bucket location issue, as I found reference around 301 for that, however I've modified the code to swap to the bucket location, to no avail.

```
import org.jets3t.service.model.S3Bucket
import org.jets3t.service.model.S3Object
import org.jets3t.service.security.AWSCredentials

@Grab('net.java.dev.jets3t:jets3t:0.9.4')

accessKey = '<key>'
secretKey = '<secret>'
bucketName = '<bucketname>'
fileName = '<fileLocation>'

credentials = new AWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey)
service = new RestS3Service(credentials)
bucket = new S3Bucket(bucketName,"eu-west-1")
println bucket.getLocation()
file = new File(fileName)
fileObject = new S3Object(file)
fileObject.key = fileName
service.putObject(bucket, fileObject)
expiryTime = new Date() + 1 // 24 hours from current date
link = service.createSignedGetUrl(bucket.name, fileObject.key, expiryTime)
println "$fileName : $link"
```

Now, this sdk has not been updated since 2015, so it's a fairly old SDK so I get the feeling it's no longer compatible (and might have some url hard coded into it) but if you had similar experience that you managed to solve out, let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Seems like this wont work for `Canada-Central-1` location. Saw this API post https://jets3t.s3.amazonaws.com/api/org/jets3t/service/model/S3Bucket.html#LOCATION_US and probably needs this location added maybe ?!

Answer (score 0):

If you come accross this and need a working groovy, I've loosely modified [this code](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjSingleOpJava.html) to work as a simple groovy

```
import com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException;
import com.amazonaws.SdkClientException;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ObjectMetadata;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.PutObjectRequest;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

Regions clientRegion = Regions.EU_WEST_1;
String bucketName = "bucketname";
String stringObjKeyName = "stringObjKeyName";
String fileObjKeyName = "fileObjKeyName";
String fileName = "fileLocation";

try {
    //This code expects that you have AWS credentials set up per:
    // https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/setup-credentials.html
    AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
            .withRegion(clientRegion)
            .build();

    // Upload a text string as a new object.
    s3Client.putObject(bucketName, stringObjKeyName, "Uploaded String Object");

    // Upload a file as a new object with ContentType and title specified.
    PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, fileObjKeyName, new File(fileName));
    ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
    metadata.setContentType("plain/text");
    metadata.addUserMetadata("x-amz-meta-title", "someTitle");
    request.setMetadata(metadata);
    s3Client.putObject(request);
} catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
    // The call was transmitted successfully, but Amazon S3 couldn't process
    // it, so it returned an error response.
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (SdkClientException e) {
    // Amazon S3 couldn't be contacted for a response, or the client
    // couldn't parse the response from Amazon S3.
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```